# How do I expand a 3D table into an array

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I expand a nested table into an array of frequency tables where I have 7x matrices (frequency tables), containing columns a and b and rows of the the two values (0.1 and 0.3) and cells of the frequency counts, for example, this table..

```
      v1      v2      v3      v4      v5      v6      v7    
a     table,2 table,2 table,2 table,2 table,2 table,2 4473   
b     table,2 table,2 table,2 table,2 table,2 table,2 table,2
```

into...

```
, , v1

    a    b
0.1 3676 3696
0.3 2288 2268

, , v2

    a    b
0.1 1536 1384
0.3 4428 4580

, , v3...until v7 (or the number of columns in the table)
```

Part of the issue seems to be that the nested table has 1x cell with 1 dimension and the rest of the cells have 2xdimensions i.e., "table,2".

Code to generate test data:

```
#This code creates 16,384 matrices of 2x7 with unique combinations of "0.1" and "0.3".

#Create some unique combinations of the two values
x.lst = list()
for (i in 1:2)
{
  x = expand.grid(rep(list(1:2), 7))
  x[x == 1] = 0.1
  x[x == 2] = 0.3
  x.lst[[i]] = x
}
x.lst

#Space the combinations to reduce repeated combinations between rows
x.lst[[2]] = sum(cor.vec)- x.lst[[1]]
x.lst[[2]]

#Create storage array
depth = nrow(x.lst[[1]]) * nrow(x.lst[[2]])
m.names = as.character(1:depth)
row.nam = c("a","b")
col.nam = c("v1","v2","v3","v4","v5","v6","v7")
test.arr = array(0,
                    dim = c(length(row.nam), length(col.nam), depth),
                    dimnames = list(two.names,seven.names ,m.names))


#Create the arrays
for (j in 1:depth)
{
  for (i in 1:length(row.nam))
  {
    test.arr[i, , j] = as.numeric(x.lst[[i]][j,])
  }
  
}
head(test.arr)
output.arr = apply(test.arr, MARGIN = c(1:2), table, simplify = FALSE)
output.arr
```

Comment: PS:  I have tried... unlist(table), however, this only gives me a 2D table and I lose the dimension "a" and "b".

Comment: How did you get this output?  Can you please show the code that derived the first output?  If it is `sapply`, then you need `simplify = FALSE`, (similar option in `apply`) as well

Comment: Hi akrun, Thank you for taking an interest.  The answer is after thousands of lines of code, which is not useful I know, so I´ll work now on some short code to produce some test data and post it.  Thanks Dan

Comment: Hi akrun,  The output came from: dat.array = apply(some.array, MARGIN = c(1,2), table) where some.array is an array of many matrices where there are two rows "a" and "b" and 7x columns "v1" to "v7" for each element of the array i.e. 5000 matrices.  See example above for defintions. Note that some.array is a reverse row and column matrix to the desired array (dat.array) and the desired array would contain 7x frequency count tables(matrices) with rows:" 0.1", "0.3" and columns "a" and "b" or each v1 to v7 variables. I hope that helps whilst i am working on some test data code. Thanks!

Comment: Code to generate test data has been added to the bottom of the question.  You will see that output.arr is a simplified table of 2x dimensions rather than a 3D array.  I lose the information about the split of the frequency count between the variables "a" and "b".